# How do I delete all instances of a node in all documents?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

We're changing our schema to move nodes that are protected paths into a single node to reduce the number of protected nodes we need to maintain.  e.g.

```
/specialized/protectThis1
/specialized/protectThis2
```

becomes

```
/specialized/protected/protectThis1
/specialized/protected/protectThis2
```

I've tried getting the records via cts:uris, but the number of records fills the expanded tree cache.  Any ideas on how I can clean out these nodes without filling the tree cache?

Answer (score 1):

I would break up the work and do it in a batch job. CoRB  https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2 is perfect for this.